# Papervision Render to Bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, rendering, papervision3d

Does anyone know of a way to render a 3D scene to a bitmap using the Papervision renderer?  I would like to take a freeze-frame of my scene that I can display while I change the scene in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `BitmapViewport3D` class.